# Poner círculo de color dependiendo resultado en tabla | JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy llenando una tabla por `js`, este es mi codigo:

```js
$('#table').append(//recorremos la lista llenando la tabla
    '<tr>' +
    '  <td>' + lista[i].nombre + '</td>' +
    '  <td>' + lista[i].estatus + '</td>' +
    '</tr>'
);
```

El dato que recibo de `estatus` es un `false` o un `true`. Necesito, que en vez de que aparezca la *frase*; cuando sea false poner un círculo verde y cuando sea true, sea uno rojo. Tengo esta parte del código:

```js
"class", "fa fa-circle text-danger"
```

¿Dónde tendría que poner la condición para saber el resultado?, y ¿cómo integrar eso en mi `td` para `estatus`?

Comment: Hay varias posibilidades, entre ellas utilizarlo como nombre de clase: `<td class=status-"+lista[i].estatus+"></td> Entonces puedes crear los círculos en CSS dependiende de si la celda `td` tiene clase `status-true` o `status-false`. También puedes poner la condicion en el contenido de la celda para mostrar X en lugar de lista[1].false… o puedes poner una función que lo haga a posteriori.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta esto a ver cómo te va

```js
if (lista[i].estatus) {
  estado = '<i class="fa fa-circle" style="font-size:48px;color:green"></i>';
} else {
  estado = '<i class="fa fa-circle" style="font-size:48px;color:red"></i>';
}

$("#table").append(
  // Recorremos la lista llenando la tabla
  "<tr>" +
    "<td>" + lista[i].nombre + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + estado + "</td>" +
  "</tr>"
);
```

Comment: ya lo aplique, pero no me aparece nada en mi celda de la tabla

Answer (score 1):

> **Importante:**
>
> Esta publicación utiliza **jQuery**, **Bootstrap** y **Font Awesome**, porque la pregunta está basada en estas tecnologías. Sin embargo, para el caso de JavaScript se dará un ejemplo utilizando **jQuery** y otro con **JavaScript puro**.

Partiendo de la siguiente inquietud, cito:

> El dato que recibo de `estatus` es un `false` o un `true`. Necesito, que en vez de que aparezca la *frase*; cuando sea *`false` poner un circulo verde* y cuando sea *`true`, sea uno rojo*. Tengo esta parte de código:
>
> ```js
> "class", "fa fa-circle text-danger";
> ```

Se podría conseguir creando una función:

```js
const colorSchema = (estatus) => {
  if (estatus) return "text-danger";
  return "text-success";
};
```

Que devuelva `text-success` (verde) como valor predeterminado, mientras que si `estatus` es `true` será `text-danger` (rojo) el valor resultante.

Una vez que se ha definido la función anterior se podría implementar en el siguiente fragmento:

```js
const lista = [
  { nombre: "Un nombre", estatus: false },
  { nombre: "Un segundo nombre", estatus: true },
  { nombre: "Tercer nombre", estatus: false }
];

// Esta función cambiará el color de los círculos
// en función de si estatus es «true» o no:
const colorSchema = (estatus) => {
  if (estatus) return "text-danger";
  return "text-success";
};

$(lista).each(function() {
  $('#table').append(
    '<tr>' +
    '  <td>' + this.nombre + '</td>' +
    `  <td><i class="fa fa-circle ${colorSchema(this.estatus)}"></i></td>` +
    '</tr>'
  );
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

tr td:last-child {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bibliotecas externas -->
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- Tabla sobre la que se trabaja -->
<table id="table"></table>
```

Es decir:

```js
`<td><i class="fa fa-circle ${colorSchema(this.estatus)}"></i></td>`;
```

Por lo tanto, si `this.estatus` es `true` la función devolverá `text-danger`:

```js
colorSchema(true); // text-danger
```

De lo contario:

```js
colorSchema(false); // text-success
```

Provocando el resultado observado en el *Snippet* anterior.

### JavaScript nativo

Podríamos tener los mismos resultados con JavaScript Nativo que será explicado, más adelante, en una tabla comparativa.

**Fragmento JavaScript Nativo:**

```js
const lista = [
  { nombre: "Un nombre", estatus: false },
  { nombre: "Un segundo nombre", estatus: true },
  { nombre: "Tercer nombre", estatus: false }
];

// Esta función cambiará el color de los círculos
// en función de si estatus es «true» o no:
const colorSchema = (estatus) => {
  if (estatus) return "text-danger";
  return "text-success";
};

const table = document.querySelector("#table");


if (table)
  lista.forEach((item) => {
    table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
      '<tr>' +
      '  <td>' + item.nombre + '</td>' +
      `  <td><i class="fa fa-circle ${colorSchema(item.estatus)}"></i></td>` +
      '</tr>'
    );
  });
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

tr td:last-child {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bibliotecas externas -->
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- Tabla sobre la que se trabaja -->
<table id="table"></table>
```

### Tabla comparativa

Las diferencias que hay en el código escrito con **jQuery** y **JavaScript nativo** se pueden observar en la siguiente tabla comparativa:

| Con **jQuery** | Con **JavaScript nativo** | ¿Qué hace? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `$(lista).each(function() {});` | `lista.forEach((item) => {});` | Itera el *array* de objeto, `lista`, o dicho de otra forma: recorrerlo. |
| `$('#table').append('<p>Algún texto</p>')` | `table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p>Algún texto</p>'))` | Insertar elementos HTML como cadenas (*string*). |

> Note que la idea de la función es facilitar la lectura e implementación del esquema de color con él . Por lo tanto, puede implementar el esquema de color sin utilizarla, pero se hace menos escalable de esa manera.

### Referencias

Para saber más sobre los métodos utilizados, consulte las siguientes referencias:

- [**`element.insertAdjacentHTML(position, text)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)
- [**`.append( content [, content ] )`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)
- [**`jQuery.each( array, callback )`**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)
- [**`Array.prototype.forEach()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Esta publicación va a recibir mejoras progresivamente.